# NSFetchedResultController Sction Name - Custom Sorting according to dates

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nssortdescriptor, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using NSFetchedResultController. Below is the scenario i want to achieve.

- I have a Table **Messages** with attributes **MessageDate**(i.e. NSDate). I need to sort the Messages by date labels as Today,Yesterday,Last Week and Older.
- I tried using NSSortDescriptor with selector method but the Selector method format returns only NSComparisonResult object.

Comment: Did you read about how sections work? You have sorting and section names separately in your implementation? Show the code.

Comment: Yes i did. I need to sort the dates comparing it to the current date. For Ex.if Message date is today's date it should grouped together. If its Yesterday's it should grouped in Yesterday's group and So on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sorting the results, try to add your sort descriptors in the fetch request itself. And create your NSFetchedResultController instance with this fetch request.

For example, you could use this code snippet.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"messageDate" ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *myFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"message" cacheName:nil];
```

Comment: You probably want to add some details about `sectionNameKeyPath:@"message"`